# Remove white spaces before certain characters

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace

I am trying to remove spaces from text like:

```
Ala ma kota ,psa i kanarka
, chyba . . .
```

in order to get

```
Ala ma kota,psa i kanarka, chyba...
```

I was trying with `sed` command:

```
echo $'Ala ma kota ,psa i kanarka\n, chyba . . .' | sed 's/ ,/,/g' | sed 's/ ././g'
```

It worked with `,` but with dots or new line there is still problem. It replaces both `.` and  not both of them together.

(I am using Linux.)

Comment: I will add info that in general I need to remove all white spaces before symbols like ,.?!;

Comment: You can edit posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU sed (which you have because you tagged this Linux):

```
$ echo $'Ala ma kota ,psa i kanarka\n, chyba . . .' | sed -zE 's/[[:space:]]([,.?!])/\1/g'
Ala ma kota,psa i kanarka, chyba...
```

#### How it works

- `-z`

  This tells sed to read in all the text at once, as opposed to reading in one line at a time.
- `-E`

  This tells sed to use extended regex syntax.  This eliminates the need for some ugly backslashes.
- `s/[[:space:]]([,.?!])/\1/g`

  This replaces any whitespace followed by one of `,`, `.`, `?`, or `!`, with just the punctuation mark.

  If you want to include other punctuation marks, just add them between the square brackets with the `,.?!`.

  `[[:space:]]` includes not just blanks but also tabs and newlines, etc.

#### Variation

This version with one **or more** white space characters from before the punctuation marks:

```
$ echo $'Ala ma kota   ,psa i kanarka  \n, chyba . . .' | sed -zE 's/[[:space:]]+([,.?!])/\1/g'
Ala ma kota,psa i kanarka, chyba...
```

#### Discussion

In the question, there is:

```
s/ ././g
```

Note that, in a regex, `.` is a wildcard: it matches anything.  Thus, `.` matches a blank followed by *any* character.  These two characters are replaced by `.` (because the replacement side is *not* a regex, the `.` is a literal period).  This is not what you had hoped for.